# Finding visible lines from their coordinates

Tags: algorithm

How can I use Graham scan for finding visible lines?
I saw one explanation and it says that its scan shows what lines are visible and how can we check this with this algorithm

I tried to understand but it has no sense for me

Comment: I think you need to be more specific-- reference what you've looked at, and which part you don't understand. Ideally include code/math, as appropriate.